# Storing group of character in a single element of an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am reading the contents of a file which is

```
hello ja mes 24
how are yo22u
```

I am using the below code to read from the file and store it  in an `ArrayList<Character>`.

```
int readvalue;

ArrayList<Character> store=new ArrayList<Character>();

    while ((readvalue = bufferReader.read()) != -1)
    {    
        store.add((char)readvalue);
    }

    System.out.println(store);
```

this gives  me an ouput like this:

```
[h, e, l, l, o,  , j, a,  , m, e, s, , 2, 4, 
, h, o, w,  , a, r, e,  , y, o, 2, 2, u, 
]
```

I want to group them into a single element of an array.I want the output like:

```
hello ,  ,ja, ,mes, ,24,
,how, ,are, ,you22u
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can for example use `BufferedReader#.readLine()` and `String.split("\w")`.

Comment: is there a way without using split method? i want to make achieve this by using just some loop condition and array functions.I Dont want to use regex or any built in function.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way to do it without **splits**, read chars to buffer until ' ' or end of line if you got it, save buffer to `ArrayList` and clear it for reading next word

---

Like that

```
String s = "hello ja mes 24\n"
               + "how are yo22u";
    int readvalue;

    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s));
    ArrayList<String> store=new ArrayList<String>();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((readvalue = bufferReader.read()) != -1)
    {
      if(readvalue!=' ' && readvalue!='\n'){
        builder.append((char)readvalue);
      }else{
        store.add(builder.toString());
        builder = new StringBuilder();
      }
    }

    store.add(builder.toString());

    System.out.println(store);
```

Comment: How can i store the spaces too here?

Comment: I want to groups these characters into an meaningful arraylist , for example: {hello,"letters"},{ ,"space"},{ja,"letter"},{ ,"space"},{mes,"letter"},{ ,"space"},{24,"digit"} so on...

Comment: i want to create name and value pair

Comment: if you want pair use associative array instead, java provides implementaton of that calls Map, how to do it, just check a second  ' ', its easy to add it to my example, or create your own structure for it, BTW its jSON string is not it ?

Comment: I am trying to tokenize the string.

Comment: Tokenize is the same like using split, so, you can use Scaner with pattern and just read what you want